# Why does my pop up activity appear twice? Android

Tags: android

This is the list view in my main where I pass the items of listview to the pop activity

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ( ) {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent (modificaGlicemia.this, popGlicemia.class));
            String elementoCliccato = parent.getItemAtPosition (position).toString ( );
            String[] separated = elementoCliccato.split ("\nData");
            String[] separated2 = separated[0].split (": ");
            IDSelezionato = separated2[1];
            Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(modificaGlicemia.this, popGlicemia.class);
            editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",IDSelezionato);
            startActivity(editScreenIntent);
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting an activity twice! At the bottom, you put `startActivity(editScreenIntent);` This is what is making a second activity pop up.